# Access denied for user even though I created the user account myself PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I am hosting my website on 000webhost.com and my goal is to create a database and store information from my users there.

I have created a database but I am having a problem accessing it in order to subsequently create tables. I use phpmyadmin on my local computer and it works fine.

However, on my shared host, when I create the database along with a user and password for it and try to log in to phpmyadmin using the username and password I just entered, I get an Access denied for user error.

I have tried using the DB name as the username and using the "root" username.

Any help would be appreciated.

I know this may sound like a trivial question but it is not. I have had ample experience with phpmyadmin so I would appreciate it if only those with experience using mySQL on a shared hosting platform would respond. Thanks

[image]

Comment: **000webhost** is dead if you really need a free hosting shift to `Hostinger`

Comment: If you used PHPMyAdmin to just insert a new user into the `mysql.user table`, you'll need to issue a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` command. Also, the password must be entered with the `PASSWORD` function.

Comment: CD001, that ought to be an "Answer."

Answer (score 0):

Check that your database allows remote access. You should probably have something like this:

Default settings for remote access of database users

- Allow local connections only
- Allow remote connections from any host
- Allow remote connections from

If you cannot access your database after changing it to "any host", contact your hosting provider and explain them the problem.